# How to get multiple value in a query VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to get all the data in a one column and put it on a variable.

```
Rate = Forms!frmStep4BookingUpdateRevBill.frmRateRevBill!Text0.Value(0)
Rate1 = Forms!frmStep4BookingUpdateRevBill.frmRateRevBill!Text0.Value(1)
Rate2 = Forms!frmStep4BookingUpdateRevBill.frmRateRevBill!Text0.Value(2)
```

Below form is came from a query.

[image]

i want all from this column rate code to pass on a variable.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Array variables? Recordsets? Maybe an input/output example would be nice.

Comment: I want all from this column rate code to pass in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are trying to concatenate the results in which case you need to look at Allen Browne's function here http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html